# Matrix/Vector Addition

Tags: vectors

[image]

If the sum of vectors **v** and **w** as shown in  the image above is (5,1) and the difference is (1,5). Can we fill the entire xy plane usimg combinations of  **v** and **w**?

Comment: Did you manage to make any progress? For example, could you find $\bf v$ and $\bf w$?

Comment: I have not made any progress. What would help me is if I could see a general formula for finding v and w. I am totally new to linear algebra

Comment: Here's a hint: imagine from usual algebra if you knew $a+b$ and $a-b$, could you work out the values of $a$ and $b$ (for example if $a+b=100$ and $a-b=10$, can you find what $a$ and $b$ are)? Pretty much same method would work here for finding $\bf v$ and $\bf w$.

Comment: So following your logic, I would have ([5,1] - [1,5]) / 2 = w?

Comment: Correct! $\color{grey}\,$

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth. Forgive me for being a neophyte, but how do I divide a vector?  If I am left with [4,-3] /2 = w. I don't see how to solve for w, and then in addition , I need to compute the angle between the two

Comment: To divide a vector by a number, simply divide each component by that number. Once you know what $\bf v$ and $\bf w$ are, you should know how to find the angle between them using dot products (if not, it would be best to revise how to do so).

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth I believe I have found the solution.  Can you confirm if my intuition is correct.  I rearranged the terms to solve for v and w.  To get v = (3,(5/2)) and w = (2,-(3/2)).  I then solved for the dot product which came to be 3.91.  In order to find the angle between the two vectors, I needed to use the Cos(theta) formula dividing the product of the lengths by the dot product. And finally, take the arccos of that result.  I found an answer of 76.7 degrees. But am unsure of how to tell if we can fill the entire xy plane using linear combinations of v and w